# How to reach the "send to mail recipient"

Tags: excel, vba, email

I need to automate a report, this is automated almost completely, but in the end of the process it has a specific sheet to be send by email, and they ask for a special format.

I found code that will send the email, but it does not do the same thing that I do when using it manually, "send to mail recipient" button on the Excel ribbon.

This is the code that I am using:

```
Dim aSheet As Worksheet
Dim Sendrng As Range
Dim rng As Range

On Error GoTo StopMacro

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sendrng = Worksheets("for_Mail_test").Range("A1:j42")
Set aSheet = ActiveSheet

With Sendrng
    .Parent.Select
    Set rng = ActiveCell
    .Select
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With .Parent.MailEnvelope
       .Introduction = "This is test mail 2."
        With .Item
            .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "My subject"
            .Display
        End With
    End With
  rng.Select
End With

aSheet.Select

StopMacro:
   With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .EnableEvents = True
   End With
 ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
```

There are two problems:
1 it does not keep the same format that I am on the sheet
2 when I change the method from `.send` to `.display` it does not showup

Comment: Is Outlook open when you run the code?

Comment: You misunderstood the comment on Ron's website, where you got this code from, here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail3.htm  What Ron says is, "I personally not like to use the VBA MailEnvelope code because it will use the Excel window instead of creating a separate Outlook mail. When you use the code examples in the two links below you can use .Display instead of .Send in the code and it will create a separate Outlook mail and you can view it first if you want."  This means that the code you took from that link will NOT let you use `.Display`.

Comment: It will not let you use this because it is using the Excel window and not Outlook.  The other links immediately below that line WILL let you use `.Display`.

Comment: It does look like someone may have solved the display issue here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/692050-how-display-email-before-sending-using-mailenvelope.html